# sinon spy check if function has been called error

Tags: javascript, sinon, spy

I am trying to check if a function has been called yet in my tests. I receive the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` when trying to do this. I have setup my code to use `sinon.spy()` on my function and then check the `callCount` based on this. `getMarketLabel` will **always** return a string. Below is my code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  marketLabelSpy = sinon.spy(getMarketLabel());
}); //please note this is in a describe block but didnt feel it was relevant to post it. marketLabelSpy is pre-defined.

it('should be called', () => {
  expect(marketLabelSpy).to.have.callCount(1);
})
```

Comment: what does getMarketLabel() return? To attach a sinon spy, you need to do sinon.spy(func) or sinon.spy(object, "method") or use sinon.spy() as a function itself.

Comment: edited the original post. `getMarketLabel` will always return a `string`

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, see how to use sinon spies: http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies, there is no sinon.spy method taking a string.

Comment: I am not talking about the actual spy. So, I want to use a spy on the function `getMarketLabel()` to check that said function has actually been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are calling the `getMarketLabel` function and the result of the function call (which is a string) will be used to set up your spy. That does not work as you intended.

To use a sinon spy on a function simply pass a reference to that function:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  marketLabelSpy = sinon.spy(getMarketLabel);
});
```

Comment: okay this is one step closer however, the test does not pass because it has been called 0 times. To call it, I need to pass the function a string.

Comment: `getMarketLabel(); expect(marketLabelSpy).to.have.callCount(1);`

Comment: @DevDig that doesn't call the spy, but the original function.

Comment: @robertklep In this case the spy is a wrapped  function, so the Spy is called and the original function is invoked by the Spy recording the call count, arguments etc.

Comment: @DevDig when you call `getMarketLabel()` as you suggest in your comment, you're calling the original function, not the spy ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dotowukife/edit?html,console)).

Comment: @robertklep I see what you mean now and you are right, it must read `getMarketLabelSpy() ...`.